# Is there a view in std::views or range-v3 for set operations? If not, how do I make my own?

Tags: c++, view, std-ranges, range-v3, set-operations

It would be convenient if I had a view which lets me examine the result of a set operation.
This is similar to `std::set_union`, `std::set_difference`, and `std::set_intersection`; however, it should not require modification or output into a new range.

###### Desired usage

```cpp
int a[] {1, 2, 4, 8, 16};
int b[] {1, 8, 80};
auto i = views::set_intersection(a, b); // {1, 8}
auto u = views::set_union(a, b);        // {1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 80}
auto d = views::set_difference(a, b);   // {2, 4, 16}

// note: the following syntax should also work, like for all views:
//       a | views::set_xyz(b)
```

Does such a thing exist in the standard library of any standard or perhaps in range-v3?
If not, how do I make my own?

Comment: There are set adaptors in range-v3. They will be added to the standard library, but they have a lower priority than many other adaptors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this currently works using `range-v3`:

```
#include <range/v3/view/set_algorithm.hpp>      // set_difference, set_intersection, set_symmetric_difference, set_union
#include <fmt/ranges.h>                         // println

int main()
{
    int a[] {1, 2, 4, 8, 16};
    int b[] {1, 8, 80};
    auto i = ranges::views::set_intersection(a, b);         fmt::println("{}", i);  // [1, 8]
    auto u = ranges::views::set_union(a, b);                fmt::println("{}", u);  // [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 80]
    auto d = ranges::views::set_difference(a, b);           fmt::println("{}", d);  // [2, 4, 16]
    auto s = ranges::views::set_symmetric_difference(a, b); fmt::println("{}", s);  // [2, 4, 16, 80]        
}
```

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/6dGY5db5x)

The WG21 paper [p2760r1](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2760r1.html) puts this in Tier 3 (the lowest priority) for C++26 however.

Please also note that a view will [not preserve the "set-ness" for formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77820246/819272)