# Range pipeline drops typedef used for formatting style

Tags: c++, pipeline, std-ranges, fmt, c++23

With C++23, we get pretty-printing of ranges, currently available in `{fmt}`. E.g. `std::set` is formatted with `{}` whereas sequence containers such as `std::vector` are formatted with `[]`. Internally, the `formatter` class template dispatches on the presence of a nested typedef `key_type` (which `std::set` does have and `std::vector` does not).

Piping a `std::set` into any kind of `view` will drop the `key_type` typedef and pretty-print it as a `std::vector`.

```
#include <ranges>
#include <set>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

int main()
{
    auto s = std::set<int>({ 2, 3, 5, 7 });

    fmt::println("{}", s);                                              // nice, formats as { 2, 3, 5, 7 }
    fmt::println("{}", s | std::views::reverse);                        // meh, now uses [] instead of {}
    fmt::println("{}", s | std::views::reverse | std::views::reverse);  // and it won't recover the braces
}
```

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/8Y1PbjT88)

**Question**: is there any way to preserve the "set-ness" (more generally: the formatting kind) of an input range in a pipeline?

Comment: Make a new `set` from your range? Looks obvious; am I missing something?

Comment: @anatolyg calling `ranges::to<std::set>` is expensive, I want a view, not a new container.

Comment: Whilst [range format specifications](https://fmt.dev/latest/syntax.html?highlight=formatter#range-format-specifications) use `[` and `]` brackets as the default range formatter, [it seems to provide specializations](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/master/include/fmt/ranges.h#L478) for ranges where the `range_format` is `set` (or `map`, or `sequence`). I'm surprised this doesn't work out of the box, but maybe `std::views::reverse` doesn't (yet?) preserve a `range_format` that respect the container.

Comment: @dfrib I also tried `views::drop` and some other views, none of them preserved the formatting.

Comment: @TemplateRex Maybe the feature is not yet part of `std::views`. Have you tried with `ranges/v3`, just to see if it _should_ work out of the box?

Comment: @dfrib also won't work with range-v3 https://godbolt.org/z/YjG11nn3c

Comment: @TemplateRex I just found that [clang doesn't list](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) any status for the formatting ranges paper ([p2286r8](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2286r8.html)), so possible [only parts of it](https://reviews.llvm.org/D134036) are yet implemented. You could try to see how MSVC handles it, as they [seem to have implemented](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/wiki/Changelog/80d1cda7dec5cc0b70fd639882d617f2f01aff81#expected-in-vs-2022-179-preview-2) the `range_format` parts of P2286.

Comment: I think you can make a custom range adaptor for this, [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4T48dnGT8). But as the answer says, this may not be a good idea.

Comment: @康桓瑋 tnx, I had something similar already, but `as_set` is only an end-of-pipe construct, I was looking for propapating the `key_type` all the way through the pipe.

Comment: @dfrib Definitely doesn't work out of box (I wrote the design). Intent was mainly to handle the associative containers out of the box, not so much preserve the formatting for adapted ranges. It's true that like... reversing and slicing, etc, a range don't necessary change the "map/set-ness" of it. I haven't really thought about it too much though.

Comment: @dfrib e.g. could do [this](https://godbolt.org/z/7dEbbEx3d) (or the std equivalent). Should that be the std design? It's a good question. I dunno. Maybe. This requires figuring out which adaptors are set-preserving (which is... a bunch actually. take{,_while}, drop{,_while}, filter, reverse, as_const, etc.)

Comment: @Barry that's really nice, specializing `range_format_kind` for reverse views! Even if the generic view doesn't preserve "set-ness", reverse only changes the comparator from `less` to `greater` but not the `key_type`. But I guess it's hard e.g., a monotonic `transform` that rounds double to integers might change the actual set type from `double` to `int` but not the "set-ness'. That requires a "is_monotonic" trait to detect etc. Pretty deep rabbit hole probably.

Comment: @Barry if you make that comment into an answer, I'd accept it.

Comment: @TemplateRex I think Nicol's answer is good. Like it might make sense to preserve set-ness, for instance. But preserving map-ness is more questionable? Is it really still a map anymore? Anyway this is just musing more than answer.

Comment: @Barry I believe it would make sense to at least allow (say via op-in) to propagate "set-ness" to range operations as reversing and slicing, but it is less clear-cut for maps. Which brings into question whether even "set-ness" propagation should be (even as opt-in) in std or not, as it may be confusing if some associative containers allow preserving their `range_format` whereas others do not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most properties of a container are not propagated to views into those containers. The only properties which are are those which are relevant to that container being a range: iterator categories, sizeability, etc. This is in part because logically a view does not have to follow the rules of the container it is a view of.

Consider `set`. A `set`'s elements are ordered and unique (relative to that order). A `view` of those elements don't have to maintain this property. A `transform` view of a set could use a hash-like function that generates the same value from multiple different inputs, violating the unique requirement of the `set`. It could transform elements such that they don't maintain the ordering relationship (or transform them into elements that cannot be ordered).

In your case, to `reverse` a set *fundamentally* changes the nature of the `set`. After all, the ordering function is part of the `set`'s type; it is an inherent part of that container. If you reverse the ordering, you're using a different ordering. At best, it is a `set` with a different type.

A `map` maps from keys to value. A `key_view` of a map... is just a sequence of keys. The fundamental nature of the container is lost.

Comment: Thanks, the set-ness is indeed not preserved for generic views. For the lazy set algoirthm views (range-v3), this might be added for convenience though.